# Why is this page "loading 3 times?" (Is it a misconfiguration?)

Tags: php, configuration, memcached, apc

- **Ubuntu** 10.10
- **Apache** 2.2.17
- **PHP** 5.3.4
- **APC** 3.1.6
- **Memcache** 3.0.5

Code:

```
<?php
$cache = new Memcache();
$cache->connect('localhost', 11211);

$num = 1;

if (($a = $cache->get('key')) !== false) $num = $a;
$num += 1;
$cache->set('key', $num);

echo $num;
```

Output (on three successive refreshes, just after Apache reboot):

```
2
```

then

```
5
```

then

```
8
```

Question: Why?  I'm expecting `2`, `3`, `4`.  The first page seems to check out, but subsequent page loads always increment a factor of three larger than the number I'm actually adding.  In other words, if I write

```
$num += 10;
```

Then the numbers come out `11`, `41`, `71`.  What am I doing wrong?  Did I mis-configure APC or Memcache?  I'm fairly certain APC is the problem, but if I knew for sure what the problem was then I wouldn't be asking!

**Update:** The apache access_log shows 3 distinct requests for each page load when this happens.

Comment: debugging tips- check http access logs, or make some

Comment: The apache error_log is devoid of information, and PHP is set at the highest level of debug output.

Comment: check access_log, not error_log - how many requests are there?

Comment: **1.** anything to do with APC? (I guess no) **2.** remove this line `$cache->set('key', $num);`, and test again

Comment: Memcache has a Memcache::increment function that is much more suited for this type of application.  If you call multiple sets on something that is already set then you can get a race condition that will never be reported.  Also i would do a replace if you dont want to use increment so you end up the same namespace in memory and Memcache wont pull any automagic in the background.

Comment: @chris & @StasM Good call... updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what method are you using to make the request? I have observed that some of the firefox plugins (like firebug) sometimes cause the page to be loaded multiple times for some reason. It might be worth trying using some other browser, or simply wget or curl to make the request and see if it still produces the same results.

Comment: Good call.  I've tested in both Firefox and Chrome, but each has plugins installed - just to be safe, I'll attempt a cURL request from the CLI just as soon as I'm at my workstation and see what I get.

Comment: A cURL request generates the expected output and only a single access_log line.

Comment: Following that fact to its logical conclusion, I disabled all browser extensions and saw normal behavior.  One by one I turned them back on.  Turns out, two extensions were responsible for fetching the page one extra time each.